# Joda DateTime format in scala with playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, salesforce

I am working on implementing Force.com Streaming API in my scala application using play framework, and I encounter some difficulties. I try to validate the JSON with a case class, and one field is joda.DateTime. From salesforce I receive the date like "2017-05-07T00:00:00.000+0000", and I have not managed to have the right implicit for it. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on this, if you are using Play-json. source: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json-part2/

example:

```
case class JsonExampleV1(field: String, date: DateTime)
object JsonExampleV1{
  implicit val r: Reads[JsonExampleV1] = (
    (__ \ "field").read[String] and
      (__ \ "date").read[DateTime](Reads.DefaultJodaDateReads)
    )(JsonExampleV1.apply _)
}
```

examples source code: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/scala-play-json-examples

Play has some readers for dates, like Reads.DefaultJodaDateReads. Have a look at https://github.com/playframework/play-joda/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JodaReads.scala